# mpdf fails to open image when run from console command

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, mpdf, symfony-console

I'm using Symfony 4.3
I have an `InvoiceService`, which generates invoice into pdf file.
For html content I use `\Twig\Environment::render()` method. In the template I use twig `asset()` function for an image.
When I run this service from controller, the invoice is generated without problems, but when I run this service from a console command I get error:

> Warning: fopen(/img/core-img/logo.png): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory

Should the Twig Environment be used in a different way, when not run from the controller?
This is the code responsible:

```
$html = $this->twig->render(
                'invoice.html.twig',
                array(
                    'reservation' => $reservation,
                )
            );
            $waterMarkText = ($this->kernel->getEnvironment() !== 'production') ? $this->translator->trans('invoice.test_document') : $this->translator->trans('invoice.paid');
            $this->mpdf->SetProtection(array('print'));
            $this->mpdf->SetTitle("Apartamenty Grodowa 2 - faktura");
            $this->mpdf->SetAuthor("Gall");
            $this->mpdf->SetWatermarkText($waterMarkText);
            $this->mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
            $this->mpdf->watermark_font = 'DejaVuSansCondensed';
            $this->mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.1;
            $this->mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
            $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
            $this->mpdf->Output($invoice->getFilePath(),
                Destination::FILE);
```

With `$this->twig` being `\Twig\Environment` passed through Dependency Injection
and `$this->mpdf` being

```
new Mpdf([
                'margin_left' => 20,
                'margin_right' => 15,
                'margin_top' => 48,
                'margin_bottom' => 25,
                'margin_header' => 10,
                'margin_footer' => 10
            ]);
```

I tried to include image by `asset('path/to/image')` and `absolute_url(asset('path/to/image'))`, both result in the red X in white square in place of an image. When run from controller, the image is there.

Comment: Use absolutes path, when running from console command the root directory is not the same as your project's

Comment: @DarkBee Yep, you're right about the ->Output() method. But what is the proper way for image to be rendered? I always get the red x in white sqare instead of image. Tried absolute_url(asset('path/to/image')) and some path variations, nothing works.